# SSL cert issued by trusted CA but only works on some clients?

Tags: ssl, windows-xp, ssl-certificate

We have some clients running Windows XP embedded that are rejecting our new SSL cert from GoDaddy. Upgrading these systems is not an option since they are connected via a satellite link.  Can anyone provide me direction on where to go and what to look at? SSL Checker shows it is correct. The URL shows an error but the path is correct?
[image]

Thanks for anyone who can provide a direction forward.
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long and short.  Microsoft doesn't support XP anymore and so therefore the credentials won't work.  Time to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I tried browsing the same link on my windows 7 in chrome and the certificate chain looks different. There is one more certificate in the chain (see the picture below)

[image]

Also, the whole chain except Root CA certificate (Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority) has signature algorithm sha256RSA (another picture below). It should not be an issue if your Windows Xp is updated (at least to SP3).

[image]

My guess is that `Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2`has been cross-certified and the chain builds differently on Windows XP and other newer OS. Try to check if the thumbrint of `Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2` on your XP is the same as on other OS (on mine windows 7 the thumbprint is `34 0b 28 80 f4 46 fc c0 4e 59 ed 33 f5 2b 3d 08 d6 24 29 64`). If it is different, try to manually import RootCA certificate `Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority` to Root store on Windows XP and check if the chain will change. Your goal is to make the chain (look) the same.

Comment: [This link](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=c-comm.mtllc.us) explains it. There are two certification paths. Try to use the second one.

Comment: Thanks @pepo.  I think what we are going to do is bite the bullet and workout some methodology to update all the remote XP Embeded machines to something that is not 12 years old and see it this addresses the problem.  Most likely it will.